# Упростите код python

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

упростите следующий код(именно убрать `def()` , переменную `res` , так как все в одну строку и ничего не понятно и желательно `print()` тоже сделать более проще без условных конструкций), буду благодарен, а то  `def()` еще не изучал по программе и не понимаю даже что к чему

```
def fun(num, word):
    letter = [lett for lett in set(word) if word.count(lett) == num]
    if len(letter) == 1:
        return letter[0]
    
res = [fun(num, input()) for num in [int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))]]
print(''.join(res) if all(res) else 'нечленораздельно')
```

попытка расписать `res` и `print()`:

```
n = int(input())

counts = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
words = [input() for _ in range(n)]


#for l in words[i]:
  #if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]:


if len(res) == n:
  print(res) 
else:
  print('нечленораздельно')
```

не проходит данный тест
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

а если так попробовать ;-)

```
n = int(input())

counts = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
words = [input() for _ in range(n)]

res = ''.join(map(lambda a: a[0], filter(len, [[l for l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]] for i in range(n)])))

print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

можно сделать чуть-чуть короче :)))

```
n = int(input())

res = ''.join(map(lambda a: a[0], filter(len, [[l for l in d[1] if d[1].count(l) == d[0]] for d in zip([int(input()) for _ in range(n)], [input() for _ in range(n)])])))

print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

без использования lambda (даже покороче получилось):

```
n = int(input())

counts = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]
words = [input() for _ in range(n)]

res = ''.join(a[0] for a in filter(len, [[l for l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]] for i in range(n)]))

print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

и

```
n = int(input())

res = ''.join(a[0] for a in filter(len, [[l for l in d[1] if d[1].count(l) == d[0]] for d in zip([int(input()) for _ in range(n)], [input() for _ in range(n)])]))

print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

разъяснение функционала для Марата:

```
# получить число n
n = int(input())

# получить n чисел 
counts = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

# получить n строк
words = [input() for _ in range(n)]

# сформировать слово соединением букв из массива без использования разделителя
res = ''.join(
    # сформировать массив букв из массива массивов букв выбрав из каждого массива по первой букве
    a[0] for a in filter(
        # выбрать из сформированного массива массива букв только такие массивы букв, в которых есть буквы (массивы не нулевого размера)
        len, [
            # сформировать массив букв, которые встречаются в слове заданное число раз
            [l for l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]] for i in range(n)
        ]
    )
)

# если в сформированном слове кол-во букв не соответствует кол-ву введённых слов (не равно n)
# то это означает, что какая-то буква для одного из слова найдена не была и в сформированное слово добавлена не была
print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

Теперь чуть более подробно:

логика следующая:

1. у нас есть массив кол-в встречающихся букв `counts` и массив слов `words`
2. рассматривая каждое слово мы формируем 1 букву (или не формируем, но это в итоге приведет к тому, что в сформированном в конце слове букв окажется меньше, чем `n` и будет выдано `нечленораздельно`)

поэтому идем по индексам от `0` до `n`

```
    [...] for i in range(n)
```

и формируем массив некоторого результата анализа i-ого слова из `words` и i-ого числа из `counts`

3. в каждом слове проходим по всем его буквам

   ```
    for l in words[i]
   ```
4. но только по таким буквам, чье кол-во в слове равно i-ому числу из `counts`

   ```
    l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]
   ```
5. и формируем массив из найденных букв

   ```
    [l for l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]]
   ```
6. если букв с заданным кол-вом повторений найдено не было, то получится пустой массив `[]`, чтобы он не мешал в дальнейшей работе с помощью функции `filter` оставляем только массивы символов ненулевой длины

   ```
    filter(
            len, 
            [...]
        )
   ```
7. теперь у каждого элемента массива массивов букв берется первая буква с использованием функции `map` (которая применяется к каждому элементу массива) или команды `for` и формируется массив первых букв из массива массивов

   ```
    [a[0] for a in filter(...)]
   ```
8. из массива букв формируется строка соединением букв без разделителя

   ```
    res = ''.join(...)
   ```

в результате получается слово из `n` символов - удачно собралось слово или из меньшего числа символов при неудачной сборке и это означает 'нечленораздельно'

**P.S.**

Нашел вариант без использования `filter` и код стал чуть короче, но чуть сложнее:

```
res = ''.join(a[0] for a in [[l for l in words[i] if words[i].count(l) == counts[i]] + ['*'] for i in range(n)])

print(res if res.find('*') == -1 else 'нечленораздельно')
```

необходимость использовать `filter` было то, что в коде есть обращение к 0 ячейке массива, но когда массив пустой, то происходит ошибка, поэтому такие элементы с помощью `filter` удалялись

чтобы этого не было теперь всегда к массиву в конце добавляется `'*'`, если буквы в массиве были, то звездочка ни на что не повлияет, а если букв в массиве не было, то по 0 элементу будет считана звездочка

и остаётся проверить только, что в сформированном слове нет звездочки

**P.S.**

построчный код:

```
# получить число n
n = int(input())

# получить n чисел
counts = [int(input()) for _ in range(n)]

# получить n строк
words = [input() for _ in range(n)]

# проанализировать все строки
res = []

for index in range(n):
    # сформировать массив букв, которые встречаются в слове заданное число раз
    letters = [letter for letter in words[index] if words[index].count(letter) == counts[index]]

    # если не было найдено букв, встречающихся заданное кол-во раз, то перейти к анализу следующей строки
    if len(set(letters)) != 1:
        continue

    # добавить найденную букву в результат (взять первую из найденных букв)
    res.append(letters[0])

# сформировать строку из собранных букв
res = ''.join(res)

# если в сформированном слове кол-во букв не соответствует кол-ву введённых слов (не равно n)
# то это означает, что какая-то буква для одного из слова найдена не была и в сформированное слово добавлена не была
print(res if len(res) == n else 'нечленораздельно')
```

Comment: стало более понятно, но не понимаю строчку `res` и `print`

Comment: можно как то обойтись пожалуйста без кода в одну строку в res и без lambda

Comment: марат а чем lambda не устраивает?

Comment: не изучали такой функционал, более простой изучали только , поэтому и прошу более просто как то расписать

Comment: нашел без лямбда - сейчас впишу в ответ

Comment: @марат, ловите с пояснениями алгоритм

Comment: спасибо большое, если вам не трудно можете все таки расписать строчку res простыми функциями, не в одну строку, просто все равно сложно для понимаю что в какую очередь идет и почему, я добавлю в вопрос что у меня получилось более просто расписав print и немного начав расписывать res, помогите пожалуйста полностью его расписать

Comment: марат, я же написал 8 этапов работы этой строки
каждый этап вы смело можете записать в отдельную строку
ну ок, попробую, не понимаю просто в чем сложность, когда уже так все расписано

Comment: добавил вам построчный код

Comment: спасибо большое)) но код не проходит последний тест почему то , помогите пожалуйста исправить(см выше какой именно тест) добавил в вопрос

Comment: известно что за тест? или почему не проходит? медленно работает или что?

Comment: известно, выше прикрепил, там неверный ответ

Comment: не понял - по правилам там же 'сон' должен получиться - с встречается 1 раз о - 2 раза, н - 3 раза

Comment: ну по логике да, но неправильно все равно

Comment: разобрался - когда несколько букв встречаются одинаковое кол-во раз - то это неоднозначность и мы не можем выбрать нужную букву, поэтому надо выдавать `нечленораздельно` - лечится исправлением 1 строчки кода - вместо `if len(letters) == 0` надо сделать `if len(set(letters)) != 1:`, т.е. `set` даёт уникальные буквы только и их кол-во должно равнять 1. Внес изменения в последний код - пользуйтесь